# Jquery: How to remove strikethrough on second click?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm just learning Jquery and wanted to use a button to add a "text-decoration" to a list item when clicked.  The problem I have is that I can't use the same button to turn the "text-decoration" back to "none" on the second click?

Here is the Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button1").click(function() {
    $("ul li:nth-child(1)").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    });
});
```

I tried copying line 2 and 3 and changing the text-decoration to "none" within the same function but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define a class in your CSS:

```
.stroked{ text-decoration: line-through; }
```

then just:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button1").click(function() {
    $("ul li:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('stroked');
    });
});
```

Edit: as you are learning the basics of jQuery, consider caching your selectors [if their content is not changing through page lifecycle]:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $li = $("ul li:nth-child(1)");

    $(".button1").click(function() {
      $li.toggleClass('stroked');
    });
});
```

So you do not have to perform the selection on every click.

Answer (score 3):

You should instead use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button1").click(function() {
        $("ul li:nth-child(1)").toggleClass("test");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `.css()` callback function:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(1)").css("text-decoration", function(_, td) {
    return td.indexOf("line-through") == -1 
           ? "line-through" 
           : "none";
});
```

Comment: ooh, I like this... complex, yet simple

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement, if you wanted to keep it purely jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button1").click(function() {
    if($("ul li:nth-child(1)").attr('text-decoration')){
       $("ul li:nth-child(1)").removeAttr('text-decoration');
    }
    Else{
       $("ul li:nth-child(1)").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    }
    });
});
```

otherwise, you can use `toggleClass` which is a little simpler to use, not to mention you could then use that class and the jQuery `toggleClass` to add/remove a strike-through anything

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it simple like this:

```
if (condition) {
  $("#yourId").wrap("<strike>");
} else {
  $("#yourId").unwrap(); //to remove the strike
}
```